# Focus on prompt windows in sublime 3 instead of touchbar on macbook pro 2016

Tags: mac, sublime-text-3

Whenever I close a file in Sublime 3 I'm prompted with the usual popup (Don't Save, Cancel, Save), but on the new macbook pro 2016, I cannot 'tab select' the options in the popup, but the options shows op on the touch bar. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: By default, I can't select the options in the popup either (on a Mac mini – so no touchbar). This needs to be enabled as [described here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55292/how-do-i-negotiate-dialogue-boxes-using-the-keyboard-only). Not sure if this solves your problem though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your System Preferences, click on *Keyboard* and select the *Shortcuts tab*. Activate *All controls* in the Full Keyboard Access setting.